# Perl parallel system/exec calls depending on CPU usage?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, cron, fork, cpu-usage

I have a perl.cron script running.
This script is only hosting exec-calls to other perl scripts.

As of the nature of exec and system calls, the cron-script starts a new process and waits fot it to finish, then calling the next script.

**Is there a way to make my cron-script monitor my cpu usage and when cpu usage is below e.g. 50 %, it should start the next process until the given cpu usage is reached?**

Thanks in advance